# Are 'distinct' operations on Structured Streaming Datasets not supported?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

From the spark structured streaming docs, [unsupported operations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#unsupported-operations) contain that

> Distinct operations on streaming Datasets are not supported.

However, there is a `distinct()` method in the API and I can also call `distinct()` after streaming DateSet.

```java
  public final class JavaStructuredNetworkWordDistinct {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir","C://hadoop" );
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("JavaStructuredNetworkWordDistinct")
            .config("spark.master", "local[*]")
            .getOrCreate();
    spark.sparkContext().setLogLevel("ERROR");
    spark.conf().set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",4);
    // Read all the csv files written atomically in a directory
    StructType userSchema = new StructType().add("event_time", "string").add("id", "string");
    Dataset<Tuple2<Timestamp, String>> dropStream = spark
            .readStream()
            .option("sep", ",")
            .schema(userSchema)      // Specify schema of the csv files
            .csv("D:\\deduplication")
            .selectExpr("to_timestamp(event_time,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as event_time","id as id")
            .as(Encoders.tuple(Encoders.TIMESTAMP(), Encoders.STRING()));

    StreamingQuery outerQuery =  execDeduplicationDistinct(spark,dropStream);
    outerQuery.awaitTermination();
  }


  private static StreamingQuery execDeduplicationDistinct(SparkSession spark, Dataset<Tuple2<Timestamp, String>> dropStream) {

    Dataset<Tuple2<Timestamp, String>> dropDuplicatesStream = dropStream.distinct();
    // Start running the query that prints the running counts to the console
    StreamingQuery query = dropDuplicatesStream.writeStream()
            .outputMode("append")
            .format("console")
            .start();
    return query;
  }
}
```

And there only one file under the folder `D:\\deduplication` , content are

```
event_time,word
2022-04-10 11:44:00,word1
2022-04-10 11:45:00,word2
2022-04-10 11:45:00,word2
2022-04-10 11:45:00,word2
```

finally , the result shows that

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+-------------------+-----+
|         event_time|   id|
+-------------------+-----+
|2022-04-10 11:44:00|word1|
|2022-04-10 11:45:00|word2|
|               null| word|
+-------------------+-----+
```

so ? what is wrong when I understand `distinct`?

And, I also run socket streaming.
Code is

```scala
object StructuredNetworkWordCountDistinct {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val host = args(0)
    val port = args(1).toInt
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount")
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",4)
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    import spark.implicits._

    // Create DataFrame representing the stream of input lines from connection to host:port
    val lines: DataFrame = spark.readStream
      .format("socket")
      .option("host", host)
      .option("port", port)
      .load()
    // Split the lines into words
    val words = lines.as[String].flatMap(_.split(" "))
    // Generate running word count
    val wordCounts = words.distinct()
    // Start running the query that prints the running counts to the console
    val query = wordCounts.writeStream
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("1 second"))  // only change in query
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

and start netcat with  `nc -L -p 9999`.
Firstly, input `v1` and the all output batchs results are

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
+-----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|   v1|
+-----+
```

and secondly, input `v1` again, and new output batch result is

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 2
-------------------------------------------
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
+-----+
```

And spark seems to remembered first `v1` (batch) to distinct second batch result.

Comment: Just updated the answer after KAFKA check.

Answer (score 0):

> "...Some Dataframe operations cannot be supported with Spark
> Structured Streaming, e.g. distinct, sorting, etc. as for those
> transformations Spark would need to store the entire data in memory.
> ..."
>
> Badly explained.

This type of query with `complete` mode does not work with distinct like operation:

```
val mappedDF = jsonEdits.groupBy($"user").agg(countDistinct($"userURL").as("cnt"))
```

It returns:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Distinct aggregations are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets. Consider using approx_count_distinct() instead.
```

If using `append` mode, it needs a `watermark` also.

> Your query is a simple `append`; there a `distinct` Without
> aggregation. This is a *trivial matter* for Spark at the micro batch
> level, it has no state issue or agg's to consider, and just processes
> the current micro batch, as you  observed. Doc's are a little poor in
> this regard.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but there are still a problem that makes me confused.  Said that : `... it has no state issue or agg's to consider, and just processes the current micro batch ...`.  When changed to socket source and alse use `append` mode .  It seems to not only process current micro-batch , but remember the last old events (state) . e.g., input `v1` ,and  spark output batch1  result `v1` ，and input `v1` again，spark output batch2 result nothing .

Comment: And `append` mode using a watermark ,It also returns: `Distinct aggregations are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets. Consider using approx_count_distinct() instead.;;` so , I think doc should say: `Distinct operations with aggregation (state) on streaming Datasets are not supported.`  Is right?

Comment: Well, sometimes Spark has some bugs and does thing differently than generate an error. Yes, the wording is a little odd.

Comment: hard to believe append causes all rows to be re-evaluated. Can you run it again pls and show output.

Comment: have updated my question ,and shown output.@thebulephantom

Comment: Oh right, that is a common startup issue with sp str str. The answer is thus correct you can assume. Hard to explain the internals, but you see v1 only once.